# Is it possible to have a flexbox with auto margins but fixed gutters?

Tags: flexbox

I have been using flexbox for a little while now. It is a really powerful feature but seems to have some pitfalls.

I have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tupira/1seoyL5z/2/) as an example but I basically want to have a layout which consists of:

1) A `thumbnails` container without an assigned width but auto margins so it is always centered.

2) `.thumbnail` child elements with a `140px x 140px` dimensions with a fixed gutter of `30px` in between

the problem is that because I cannot assign a width to the `thumbnails`container, I am unable to target the last row `thumbnail:nth-child(lastone)` in order to prevent it from adding a 30px margin as I do not know how many per row there will be. As a result `thumbnails` cannot be centered as it will always have an extra padding of 30px on the right.

Is it actually possible to fix this issue without having to calculate screen size values with js?

Comment: Your jsfiddle is empty

Comment: Try now (link above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a play around and the best way to achieve what you want (assuming you want all the thumbnails to touch the sides of the container) is to give all the thumbnails a margin of 15px (so when two are next to each other both margins are added and give 30px) and then remove the extra space around the outside by giving the container a negative margin.

HTML:

```
<button id="add">Add Child</button>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail th-1"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

#thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:auto;
  margin: -15px; /* Negative margin to counter outer thumbnails */
  justify-content:center;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 140px;
  background: red;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 15px; /* Margin applied to all sides */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ho02uLpz/2/

If you don't mind having the 15px margin around all the thumbnails you can remove the negative margin from the `#thumbnails` container.

Comment: This works for me, without the negative margin. Thanks!